# Angular 2 - prevent loading parent component in child route

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I my project I have two routes: missing and missing/:id.

What I want to archieve is when I'm entering missing/:id I don't want to load parent component.

My first configuration looked like this:

```
{
      path: 'missing',
      component: MissingComponent,
      children: [
        {
           path: ':id',
           component: MissingDetailsComponent,
        }
      ]
    }
```

:id was loaded in `router-outlet` in MissingComponent. Then I changed it to:

```
{
          path: 'missing',
          component: MissingComponent,

        },
        {
          path: 'missing/:id',
          component: MissingDetailsComponent,
        }
```

With no children array. But it still loads data from MissingComponent.

Is there any solution to avoid parent component loading?

I was thinking about adding some code which blocks parent scripts if child is opened(via router events), but I don't thnik if this is correct way to do so. Maybe there's simplier way.

Thanks.

E: What I found out is that during routing to child component, parent component is not destroyed so all subscriptions are not terminated. It's confusing because it is not rendered on the view but still listening to events.

Comment: You can try adding `pathMatch: 'full'` to your configuration for the path 'missing'. See the [documentation](https://angular.io/api/router/Route#pathMatch).

Comment: Yet the documentation also says: By default, the router checks URL elements from the left to see if the URL matches a given path and stops when there is a config match. Importantly there must still be a config match **for each segment** of the URL.

I also tried to reproduced your router-configuration in my Angular 15 app. Strangely it worked perfectly.

Comment: the general rule is put specific routes first, `path/:id` is more specific than `path` so move the declaration of path/id above path, with Angular routers, order does matter.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I followed all steps and result is still the same. But if @kellermat example is working that maybe problem is somewhere else. I will try to find it.